# Java regex matching in between two pattern

Tags: java, regex

I've a url like

```
https://example.com/helloworld/@.id==imhere
```

or

```
https://example.com/helloworld/@.id==imnothere?param1=value1
```

I want to extract the value `imhere` or `imnothere` from these URLs.

```
Pattern.compile("(?<=helloworld\\/@\\.id==).*(?=\\?)");
```

Problem with this one is it does not found ? (first case) it is not matching the pattern.

Can someone help me to fix this? 
Sorry my mistake, I've missed @.id phase in the URL.

Answer (score 2):

This expression should do it:

```
^.*@==(.*?)(?:\?.*)?$
```

[<kbd>regex101 demo</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/HRian0/1)

It searches for `@==` and grabs everything after this string, up to a `?`, if any. The trick is the lazy `*`.

The actual match is in group one. Translated to Java, a sample application would look like this:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

class Sample {
    private static final String PATTERN_TEMPLATE = "^.*@==(.*?)(?:\\?.*)?$";

    public static void main (final String... args) {
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(PATTERN_TEMPLATE);

        final String firstTest = "https://example.com/helloworld/.@==imhere";
        final Matcher firstMatcher = pattern.matcher(firstTest);
        if (firstMatcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println(firstMatcher.group(1));
        }

        final String secondTest =
                "https://example.com/helloworld/.@==imnothere?param1=value1";
        final Matcher secondMatcher = pattern.matcher(secondTest);
        if (secondMatcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println(secondMatcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/xBUp5Z)

If one wants to incorporate the regex to also validate that `helloworld/.` is present, then one can simply extend the regular expression:

```
^.*helloworld\/\.@==(.*?)(?:\?.*)?$
```

[<kbd>regex101 demo</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/HRian0/2)

But one should be careful when translating this expression to Java. The backslashes have to be escaped.

Comment: Thank you very much. Since I missed the 'id' phase in the URL, after adding it in your expression it worked for me. I've to use the phrase helloworld, so using the second expression as : "^.*helloworld\\/@\\.id==(.*?)(?:\\?.*)?$"

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to upvote and or/mark my post as answer.

Answer (score -1):

To match after a specific phrase up to the next whitespace, question mark, or end of string, the Java regex is this :

`"(?<=helloworld/\\.@==).*?(?![^\\s?])"`

https://regex101.com/r/9yraPt/1

If spanning lines, ad `(?s)` to the beginning.

Answer (score -1):

I would not use a regular expression for this.  It’s a heavyweight solution for a simple problem.

Use the [URI class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html) to extract the path (the part between the host and the `?`, if any), then look for the last occurrence of `==`:

```
String s = "https://example.com/helloworld/@.id==imnothere?param1=value1";

URI uri = URI.create(s);
String path = uri.getPath();
int idAttributeIndex = path.lastIndexOf("@.id==");
String id = path.substring(idAttributeIndex + 6);
```